# Firebase & IOS - cannot query immediately after adding user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm adding a new Auth user but then seem unable to query the database in the completion block for additional data. the same query works fine however in a different view controller.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(emailAddress.lowercaseString, 
                   password: password, completion: { user, error in

   if let validUser = user {

      let newUsersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

      newUsersRef.queryOrderedByChild("body/email")
                 .queryEqualToValue(emailAddress.lowercaseString)
                 .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in ...
```

will return a null snapshot. I understood from the docs that users are immediately logged in when creating via createUserWithEmail.
what am I missing ? 
thanks

Comment: Given that the node you're trying to load it mailed on the email address you're registering (there's no need to lowercase this in the call to `createUserWithEmail` btw), I doubt the node exists in your database (user data is not automatically added to the database). So in that case, the `.Value` will correctly fire with `nil`.

Comment: yes they do exist in /users. user records are added there first through a separate process and i need to link them based on the email address, hence the lookup.